# I am trying to look through an array and pick out certain strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

We have to do complete a task for my AP Computer Science class, and I figured out the base of the code, but I am stuck on a part. Here is the link to complete the assignment if you would like to try it out.

LINK: http://codingbat.com/prob/p254067

Here is my code so far:

```
public int numVworthy(String wordsList[]) {
  int count = 0;
  String w = "w";
  String v = "v";

  for(int i = 0; i < wordsList.length; i++) {
    if(wordsList[i].contains(v) && wordsList.length - 1 == 0) {
      count++;
    }

    if(wordsList[i].contains(v) && i == 0) {
      if(!wordsList[i + 1].contains(w)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if(wordsList[i].contains(v) && i == wordsList.length - 1) {
      if(!wordsList[i - 1].contains(w)) {
        count++;
      }
    }

  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: What part exactly are you having trouble with other than the fact that you need to read the JavaDoc's on the String.contains() method.

Comment: What kind of stuck?? What is the problem you are actually having ??

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you are using is incorect

it should be

```
if(wordsList[i].contains(v)) {
```

Comment: Ok that helped alot but i'm still kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0):

this code should work

```
public int numVworthy(String wordsList[]) { 
  int count = 0;
  String w = "w";
  String v = "v";

  for(int i = 0; i < wordsList.length; i++) { 
    // first we check the final decision: does the word contain v or not
    if(wordsList[i].contains(v)){ 
      // then we check if there's only one word, since this is a special case, where it'll always count
      if(wordsList.length == 1){
        count++;
      }
      // otherwise we'll see if the previous word contains a w
      // if there is a previous word
      else if(i>0 && !wordsList[i-1].contains(w)){
          // if the previous word doesn't contain a w we'll see if the next
          // word contains a w, if there is a next word
          if((i+1)<wordsList.length && !wordsList[i+1].contains(w)){
            // all conditions are satisfied
            count++;
          // if there isn't a next word all conditions have been satisfied
          } else if(i==(wordsList.length - 1)){
            count++;
          }
       // if there isn't a previous word, the only condition is that the next
       // word doesn't contain a w
        } else if(i==0 && (i+1)<wordsList.length && !wordsList[i+1].contains(w)){
            count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

I hope you find this helpful  This exercise is a matter of going through all scenarios, in this case:

1. There is only one element and it contains a v
2. There are two elements, the first one contains a v
3. There are two elements, the second one contains a v
4. There are three or more elements, the first one contains a v and the second one doesn't
5. There are three or more elements, the last one contains a v and the one before that doesn't
6. There are three or more element, a middle element contains a v and the one before and after it don't

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
enter code here

  public int numVworthy(String wordsList[]) {
  int count = 0;
  String w = "w";
  String v = "v";
  bool prevw = false;
  bool flagv = false;
  for(int i = 0; i < wordsList.length; i++) {
     if(!wordsList[i].contains(w) && !prevw) {
       prevw = true;

        }else if(wordsList[i].contains(v) && !flagv && prevw) {
           flagv= true;
       }

        else if(!wordsList[i].contains(w) && flagv)
        {
           count++;
        }
        else
         {
            prevw=nextw=flagv= false;
            i=-2;  // used to recheck this line for prev two that are excaped      beacuse of the prevw flag is true
         }




          }
          return count;
           }
```

Answer (score -1):

This code worked fine! Using just one if.

```
public int numVworthy(String wordsList[]) {

      int counter = 0;

          for(int i=0; i < wordsList.length; i++){

          if(wordsList[i].contains("v")){
              if(!(i > 0 && wordsList[i-1].contains("w")) && !(wordsList.length-1 > i && wordsList[i+1].contains("w"))){
                  counter++;
              }

          }
      }
      return counter;
}
```